# Find the history of commands applied to the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to find the history of commands applied to the kubernetes cluster by kubectl?
For example, I want to know the last applied command was

```
kubectl apply -f x.yaml
```

or

```
kubectl apply -f y.yaml
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the audit logs?

Comment: Sometimes resources will have an annotation specifying their previous configuration changes. But it only shows you 1 previous "version". If you are looking for deployment history changes, you can look for ReplicaSets, or run `kubectl rollout history`

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and found this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#audit-logs, I didn't yet read it but I hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kubectl apply view-last-applied` command to find the last applied configuration:

```
➜  ~ kubectl apply view-last-applied --help

View the latest last-applied-configuration annotations by type/name or file.

 The default output will be printed to stdout in YAML format. One can use -o option to change output format.

Examples:
  # View the last-applied-configuration annotations by type/name in YAML.
  kubectl apply view-last-applied deployment/nginx
  
  # View the last-applied-configuration annotations by file in JSON
  kubectl apply view-last-applied -f deploy.yaml -o json

[...]
```

To get the full history from the beginning of a cluster creation you should use [audit logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) as already mentioned in comments by @Jonas.

additionally, if you adopt gitops you could have all your cluster state under version control. It will allow you to trace back all the changes made to your cluster.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your response, but what I am looking for is just the command applied, not the configuration.

Comment: The command you applied is most probably in your bash history

Comment: This is the case if you are the only user working with the cluster.